# Enzyme Blocking Probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory

A linear structure Polymer has $12$ binding sites, $6$ inhibitors. Each inhibitor occupies $1$ binding site, and an enzyme requires at least $4$ consecutive non-occupied binding sites to bind with the polymer. What is the probability that a polymer with $6$ inhibitors can still bind with an enzyme?

So I have been trying to set up the probability model. The enzyme requires $4$ consecutive open sites, but there are also $6$ inhibitors, which means that the scenarios where there are $\{4, 5, 6\}$ consecutive open sites would allow the enzyme to bind. But I am having trouble with the math, any help?

Comment: You talk about probability, but there's no random element in what you've described. Are the inhibitors randomly distributed across the binding sites? If so, according to what distribution? Uniformly independently?

Comment: The inhibitors are randomly distributed across the binding sites, they are uniformly independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that each site can be occupied by at most one inhibitor.

There are $\binom86=28$ ways in which $4$ particular consecutive sites can be free, $\binom76=7$ ways in which $5$ particular consecutive sites can be free, and $\binom66=1$ way in which $6$ particular consecutive sites can be free.

We can choose $4$ consecutive sites in $9$ ways, so there are $9\cdot28=252$ ways to leave $4$ consecutive sites free. However, that double-counts configurations in which $5$ consecutive sites are free, so we have to subtract those. We can choose $5$ consecutive sites in $8$ ways, so there are $8\cdot7=56$ ways to leave $5$ consecutive sites free, for a total of $252-56=196$. Note that configurations in which $6$ consecutive sites are free have been counted $3-2=1$ time, as required.

In all, there are $\binom{12}6=924$ ways to distribute the inhibitors over the sites, so the probability that $6$ consecutive sites are free is

$$
\frac{196}{924}=\frac7{33}\approx21\%\;.
$$